# How to only show upcoming Events in v-for Loop?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

We have an Events app with a loop of Events. Each event has a start date. In our loop, I want to only show events where the startDate is after the current date.

Our template:

```
<v-card flat class="pa-2 mb-3 eventcard" v-for="event in filteredEvents.reverse()" :key="event.id">
        <v-layout v-if="event.title" row wrap>
          <v-flex md3>
          <img class="media-image pr-1 pl-1" v-bind:src='event.imageUrl'>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex md9>
            <v-card-title primary-title class="pb-0 pt-0 text-xs-center">

            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text class="pt-0 text-xs-center text-md-left">
                <div class="display-1 mb-1"><router-link :to="`/events/` + event.slug" class="td-none plink">{{event.title}}</router-link></div>

                <div class="caption">Cerda Productions | {{ event.startDate | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }} - {{ event.endDate | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }} | {{ event.venue }} - {{ event.city }}, {{ event.state }}</div>

                <router-link :to="`/events/` + event.slug" class="td-none plink"><v-btn round color="accent" class="mt-2">Learn More<v-icon right>chevron_right</v-icon></v-btn></router-link>

            </v-card-text>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
    </v-card>
```

Computed:

```
filteredEvents: function(){
    return this.$store.getters.loadedEvents.filter((event) => {
      return event.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate);
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard `Date` comparison added to your computed property:

```
filteredEvents: function(){
    let currentDate = new Date();
    return this.$store.getters.loadedEvents.filter((event) => {
      return event.title.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
                 && new Date(event.startDate) > currentDate;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return new Date(b.startDate) - new Date(a.startDate);
    })
  },
```

I added it to the current `filter` function. You could chain a new `filter` call instead. No difference in terms of performance.

Though it likely won't matter (your array is probably not large enough for it to matter), it is preferable to `filter` before the `sort`, as you are now.